# mongo explain executionStats not matching count performance

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I'm running mongo 3.2.10 (WiredTiger) and I have a collection with ~42 million documents. I have a simple index on a single field, and the field is >= 0 for ~10 million documents.

If I run:

```
db.sitemap_items.explain('executionStats').find({'my_field': {'$gt': 0}}).count()
```

it shows executionTimeMillis: ~3 seconds

If I run:

```
db.sitemap_items.find({'my_field': {'$gt': 0}}).count()
```

it takes about 60 seconds!

Can anyone explain the discrepancy between these two numbers? It seems that the actual count operation is doing a lot more than the one which runs as part of explain('executionStats').

Comment: find() return a cursor containing the results, but doesn't iterate over them, whereas count() has to iterate over the entire sitemap_items collection

Comment: @felix, find(query).count() is equivalent to count(query), so both operations are count operations (not find operations)

Comment: The discrepancy in timing went away when I upgraded from mongo 3.2.10 to 3.2.11. I looked through the changelog and didn't see anything obvious but this may have been some kind of (pretty serious in my case!) bug that was fixed in mongo itself